# XSLT: XML first attribute need to be transformed to element with value of second attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

Using xslt 1.0, I need to transform input xml to output xml (see below).
In other words, every "Data" element with two attributes "Field" and "Value" need to be converted to element with name of "Field" value and with "Value" value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataFile>
<DataSet Name="DataSet1">
  <Data Field="Id" Value="111"/>
  <Data Field="Name" Value="John"/>
  <Data Field="ZIP" Value="10000"/>
  <Data Field="Phone" Value="0102030405"/>
</DataSet>
<DataSet Name="DataSet2">
  <Data Field="Id" Value="222"/>
  <Data Field="Name" Value="James"/>
  <Data Field="ZIP" Value="10020"/>
</DataSet>
<DataSet Name="DataSet3">
  <Data Field="Id" Value="333"/>
  <Data Field="Name" Value="Mike"/>
  <Data Field="Phone" Value="0607080910"/>
</DataSet>
</DataFile>
```

I need out file:

```
<DataFile>
   <DataSet Name="DataSet1">
      <Id>111</Id>
      <Name>John</Name>
      <ZIP>10000</ZIP>
      <Phone>0102030405</Phone>
   </DataSet>
   <DataSet Name="DataSet2">
      <Id>222</Id>
      <Name>James</Name>
      <ZIP>10020</ZIP>
   </DataSet>
   <DataSet Name="DataSet3">
      <Id>333</Id>
      <Name>Mike</Name>
      <Phone>0607080910</Phone>
   </DataSet>
</DataFile>
```

I try XSLT from similar example but it doesnt work (with error like "Unable to generate the XML document using the provided XML/XSL input. Invalid element name (empty sequence)".

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Data">
      <xsl:element name="{@name}" >
      <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `<xsl:element name="{@name}">` you want `<xsl:element name="{@Field}">`.